# Conditionally select a column from a separate table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of notifications, events, and organizations. Notifications have a column called `event-id`, that can be null. I'm trying to select notifications, with the organization.timezone for notifications that have an event, and just the notifications with no timezone (or null) that have no event. Here is an example of what the tables might look like (with unrelated fields removed)

notifications table

```
id | message | event-id

0  |  "a"    | 0

1  |  "b"    | nil
```

events table

```
id | org-id 

0  |  0    

1  |  1
```

organizations table

```
id | timezone

0  |  "Eastern"    

1  |  "Other"
```

My query should return

```
id | message | timezone

0  |  "a"    | "eastern"

1  |  "b"    | nil
```

My attempt is as follows (translated from clojure honeysql, so sorry if there is a typo):

```
Select notifications.id, notifications.message, (case when notifications.event-id then organizations.timezone end) 
where (or (= notifications.event-id nil) 
          (and (= notifications.event-id events.id)
               (= events.org-id organizations.id))
end
```

But I get

My query should return

```
id | message | case

0  |  "a"    | "eastern"

1  |  "b"    | nil

1  |  "b"    | nil
```

How do I fix this so i don't get repeat values for every notification for which event-id is null?

Answer (score 0):

Your translated SQL is not valid so it's difficult to say why you're getting duplicates, but here's some valid SQL which will return the result you want and hopefully you can translate it to your original format.

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE notifications (
  "id" INTEGER,
  "message" VARCHAR(3),
  "event-id" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO notifications
  ("id", "message", "event-id")
VALUES
  ('0', 'a', '0'),
  ('1', 'b', NULL);

CREATE TABLE events (
  "id" INTEGER,
  "org-id" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO events
  ("id", "org-id")
VALUES
  ('0', '0'),
  ('1', '1');

CREATE TABLE organizations (
  "id" INTEGER,
  "timezone" VARCHAR(9)
);

INSERT INTO organizations
  ("id", "timezone")
VALUES
  ('0', 'Eastern'),
  ('1', 'Other');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT n.id, n.message, o.timezone
FROM notifications n
LEFT JOIN events e
    ON e.id = n."event-id"
LEFT JOIN organizations o
    ON o.id = e."org-id";
```

**Result**

```
| id  | message | timezone |
| --- | ------- | -------- |
| 0   | a       | Eastern  |
| 1   | b       |          |
```

---

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwjx9TKvmvGrKCkcWd31oS/0)